# Oracle Client Installation 'win64_11gR2_client' failed on Windows 7

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, client

I am trying to install Oracle client 11gR2 with following environment.

**Environment:**
-Windows 7 Pro
-8GB RAM
-More than Enough space in C: drive (106 GB).
-No file permission issue for temp directory

I downloaded fresh media from oracle website. When I double click on setup.exe black screen comes and disappears as in [image]

I have checked all prerequisites for oracle client installation and all goes well.

Any help will be much appreciated. Many Thanks

Comment: It may take a few minutes until the Oracle Installer (OUI) starts, that's normal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It never worked like this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. I copied the media on desktop and restarted setup.exe and all worked like charm. Reason might **be long media path**.

Comment: Maybe more the fact of having space characters in the path

Comment: I also checked the same. Media on desktop with space in path did work well!

Answer (score 0):

Logging in as the local administrator and running the setup.exe worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Wernfried Domscheit said, in my case it was a space in the folder containing setup.exe